# Java Swing: How to build an Executable Jar When Maven is used?

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I am trying to develop a Swing app with Maven. Using Netbeans IDE. Everything is fine, app developed as needed and from the IDE I can run it absolutely fine.

However when I build it, I cant double click on this and run. A black windows appear and disappear in a moment.

I tried `java -jar <jar-file-name>`, same result.

I tried `java -cp <jar-file-name> main-class-name` the below error occured.

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.forecastrx.forecastrxconverter.ui.Home
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap
```

I want this app to be open but have no idea on how to get this to work.

Below is my Java information

[image]

Below is my `POM` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.forecastrx</groupId>
    <artifactId>ForecastRxConverter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <!--NEWLY ADDED SECTION BELOW -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.forecastrx.forecastrxconverter.ui.Home</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What can I do to get this work?

Comment: You have to add either maven-shade-plugin or maven-assembly-plugin to create an executable jar otherwise the dependencies are not packaged into the resulting jar file..

Comment: @khmarbaise: Just adding the shade plugin to POM is sufficient?

Comment: @JFMeier: Thanks, that did work. But I need to run it via the terminal. Why it do not get open with double click?

Comment: Write a bat or sh file that calls java.